# Ошибка генерации @vue/cli проекта в WebStrom

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webstorm

Помогите! Не генерируется проект  @vue/cli 3 в WebStrom. До переустановки windows 10  генерировался а после нет! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта ошибка исправлена в 2018.2 - см. [WEB-32583](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32583). Бета версия доступна для скачивания на  https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/

Comment: Спасибо, долго не мог найти причину ошибки!